# How to vertically center an element inside another while both having unknown heights?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a responsive site, so most of the elements I'm working with have unknown heights. Here's what I got...

```
 <div class="main">
   <div class="submenu">
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .main {
 background: #0e0e0e;
 width: 80%;
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
 }

 .main .submenu {
 background: #e62e7a;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 15%;
 }

 .submenu ul {
 background: pink;
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 }

 .submenu ul li {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 }

 .submenu ul li a {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 padding: 8px;
 }
```

Okay. So I have div with a proportional size inside a div with a changing height and width. I have two problems:

1) How do I vertically center the anchors at the end of the code inside the .submenu div? Apparently percentage line height doesn't work, and I'm not sure why, but the table display trick does not work either.

2) Also in the anchors, the padding escapes its parent boundaries. The text is perfectly at top, but the padding transparently black background of the anchors is escaping the parent. Why is that?

P.S. as for .main height I added a div inside with a padding-top of 50% to set its height relatively to its width.

Answer (score 0):

This article may be able to help: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Basically, by using `display: table-cell;`, you can use `vertical-align: middle;` on your content.

Here's a JSFiddle updated to use this method:

http://jsfiddle.net/yVn7Z/

Updated CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.main {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.main .submenu {
    background: pink;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
.submenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.submenu ul li {
    display: table-cell;
}
.submenu ul li a {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 8px;
    display: block;
}
```